# Match Unknown Number of String Elements in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings that I need to conduct a search with on a certain column in a data frame:

```
search_strings = ['foo bar', 'bar such foo', 'very wow foo']
```

I am trying to retrieve rows in the dataframe that match the words in any order in each string in the list. The dataframe might look like this:

```
ID string_col
1  foo bar
2  bar foo
3  foo very bar
4  bar such foo
5  foo wow very
```

I was happy to find that I could use a '|' operator with str.contains (retrieves all 5 rows):

```
df[df['string_col'].str.contains('foo|bar')]
```

I thought I could loop through my list, split and join them with an '&' to do something similar (I erroneously believed this would retrieve 4 rows):

```
df[df['string_col'].str.contains('foo&bar')]
```

However, turns out that this is not something you can do. Any idea how I can easily retrieve matching columns based on a list of strings, each with an unknown number of words?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension on the split string, ensuring that all target words are present:

```
words = ['foo', 'bar']
df['word_match'] = [all(word in values for word in words) 
                    for values in df.string_col.str.split(" ")]

>>> df
   ID    string_col word_match
0   1       foo bar       True
1   2       bar foo       True
2   3  foo very bar       True
3   4  bar such foo       True
4   5       foo wow      False
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit df['word_match'] = [all(word in values for word in words) for values in df.string_col.str.split(" ")]
1000 loops, best of 3: 320 µs per loop

%timeit df['word_match'] = df[df['string_col'].str.contains('foo') & df['string_col'].str.contains('bar')]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

On larger datasets, the second method slightly outperforms:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df2['word_match'] = [all(word in values for word in words) for values in df2.string_col.str.split(" ")]
10 loops, best of 3: 70.9 ms per loop

%timeit df2['word_match'] = df2[df2['string_col'].str.contains('foo') & df2['string_col'].str.contains('bar')]
10 loops, best of 3: 63.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: You may want to see if there is any performance gain with your data using `all(word in set(values) for...`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass 2 conditions using `str.contains` and wrap these in parentheses and use `&`:

```
In [11]:
df[df['string_col'].str.contains('foo') & df['string_col'].str.contains('bar')]

Out[11]:
   ID    string_col
0   1       foo bar
1   2       bar foo
2   3  foo very bar
3   4  bar such foo
```

Comment: thanks! i edited my post with a little more specificity -- i have a situation where I don't know how many words I need to match.

Comment: You just defined multiple masks and `&` them all

Comment: e.g. `foo_mask = df['string_col'].str.contains('foo')  bar_mask=df['string_col'].str.contains('bar')  filtered = df[foo & bar]` You can successivley build masks like these and combine them however you want